# I have some issues when i'm trying to build a new react native project

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm trying to build a new react native project, once i do this,
only node_modules and packge.json with its lock file install, not the files of the react native project
and i got this error :

[image: this is the error when i run choco install -y nodejs-lts openjdk11].

this is the result when i run npx react-native init app_name
[image: npx react-native init app_name]

I want a build a new react native project

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=chocolatey+checksum+did+not+meet+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: your issue with jdk your jsk may be zip file you need to install exe file this will help may be

Comment: Maybe you're problem JDK you install JDK zip file you need to install JDK EXE file